# recursive dynamic template compilation in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, compilation, angular2-compiler

I've based some of my work on the same problem described in here:

dynamic template to compile dynamic Component with Angular 2.0

[How can I use/create dynamic template to compile dynamic Component with Angular 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888008/how-can-i-use-create-dynamic-template-to-compile-dynamic-component-with-angular)

The working plunker described in the question above can be found [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/wh4VJG).

The problem occours if the dynamic-detail tries to create another dynamic view that uses dynamic-detail in the template. If i try to do that i get the following exception.:

**'dynamic-detail' is not a known element:
1. If 'dynamic-detail' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.**

This is easily reprocuded by changing the logic in the plunker to create a dynamic template that outputs "`<dynamic-detail></dynamic-detail>`".

In the file "**app/dynamic/template.builder.ts**" I've changed the following code:

```
      let editorName = useTextarea 
    ? "text-editor"
    : "string-editor";
```

To

```
      let editorName = useTextarea 
    ? "dynamic-detail"
    : "string-editor";
```

When that happens i run into the exception above. Apparently the compiler is not familiar with dynamic-detail when it is done recursively.

I've tried to add the DynamicDetail to imports in the different modules without any luck. Maybe that's not part of the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your change `"text-editor"` to `"dynamic-detail"` then your template will look like:

```
<form>
  <dynamic-detail
     [propertyName]="'code'"
     [entity]="entity"
   ></dynamic-detail>
   <dynamic-detail
      [propertyName]="'description'"
      [entity]="entity"
   ></dynamic-detail>
</form>
```

`DynamicDetail` component doesn't have `propertyName` and `entity` properties.
So you can add their.

**detail.view.ts**

```
export class DynamicDetail implements AfterViewInit, OnChanges, OnDestroy, OnInit
{ 
    @Input()  public propertyName: string;
    @Input()  public entity: any;
```

Second part of solution is add this component to `RuntimeComponentModule`:

**type.builder.ts**

```
protected createComponentModule (componentType: any) {
  @NgModule({
    imports: [ 
      PartsModule,
      DynamicModule.forRoot() // this line
    ],
    declarations: [
      componentType
    ],
  })
  class RuntimeComponentModule {}

  return RuntimeComponentModule;
}
```

After that it should work **[Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/NiuDEj?p=preview)**

Comment: Thank you! That actually worked nicely! However the next propblem quickly came by. Now i want to render a dynamic-detail in one of the parts. Then i get the same error as before. If i do DynamicDetail as forwardRef in the parts.module i'll get a stack overflow exception. If I import DynamicModule.forRoot() in the partsModule i get an 'undefined exception' ... How can i have any of my parts render a dynamic-detail as well?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/UYnQHF?p=preview Look at `parts.module.ts` and `dynamic.module.ts` But if you will set the same template in dynamic component you will get circular invokation