# Angular 2: innerHTML with Template Bindings, Attribute Directives, Components

Tags: angular

In Angular 2, what is the best practice for rendering user-submitted HTML (from a markdown editor, for example) if you'd like to be able to create bindings to the elements rendered?

Currently, I'm rendering using innerHTML and a pipe that bypasses the sanitizer. Is this the only way to render this content? If so, is there a way to allow bindings, attribute directives and components within?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39771455/recursive-dynamic-template-compilation-in-angular2

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem, using innerHtml?